# Edit and onEnter event

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have problem with several things:

1. How to make `edit1.text` be blank when i hit enter (i think it should be on onEnter event but not so sure)
2. Is there any way to assign strings from `Edit1.text` to array?

With all that said all i wanna do is:

Enter a name in edit, click enter, and then enter another name in same edit and previous name to be saved in some variable or array. Is this even possible?

I tried `procedure TForm1.Edit3Enter(Sender: TObject);` but when i click enter nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `OnEnter` event is triggered when the Edit control receives keyboard input, not when the user pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. You should be using the `OnKeyPress` event for that, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    Key := #0;  
    S := Edit1.Text;
    Edit1.Clear;
    // do something with S...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's build a simple project. Add an TEdit and an TListbox to a form.

```
 unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Edit1: TEdit;
        ListBox1: TListBox;
        procedure Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
        procedure Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}
    procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     ShowMessage('On enter');
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      if Key = 13 then
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Edit1.Text);
        Edit1.Text := '';
      end;

    end;

    end.
```

To detect key pressed event use any of the Key Down/Key Up events, I used Key Down. Everytime I hit enter the string for the edit goes into the ListBox.

This is on delphi XE7.

Also for your information. onEnter event it's triggered when you set the focus on the edit field. For example on the same project assign the onEnter event. Now click on the listBox then click on the Edit1 you will trigger the onEnter event.

Comment: Er, `OnKeyDown` are `OnKeyUp` are quite different. Try for yourself with a typical Windows app. Does the control show the character when the key goes down, or when the key goes up?

Comment: It works both way, I've added the same code on keyUp and it does the same thing. It might be different but for his purpose it works.

Comment: No it does not. Read the documentation, but as a quick summary, `OnKeyDown` fires when the key goes **down** and `OnKeyUp` fires when the key goes **up**.

Comment: Well it's obvious that one is fired on down and one on up, but i don't think he will ever have a case when the on OnKeyUp won't fire in his situation, as he presses enter so it does a KeyDown and a KeyUp event. What am I missing?

Comment: The point is that the program should respond when the key is pressed because that is the platform standard. Anyway, use OnKeyPress in this case.